# Visual Studio 2019 for Mac. Where to find templates for react projects?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-mac

VS 2019 for Windows allows us to create new projects with templates for react or react+redux.

Where to find such an option in VS 2019 for Mac?

[image]

Comment: Downvote without explanation :) Tell me what is wrong, where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [source code](https://github.com/mono/monodevelop/tree/master/main/src/addins/MonoDevelop.AspNetCore/Templates), there is no such template yet.

Alternatively, you can use `dotnet new` command at terminal to create new projects, [as documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/react?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio).

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio for Mac 8.1 will include ASP.NET Core React project templates.

[Visual Studio for Mac 8.1 preview release notes for ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2019-mac-preview-relnotes#aspnet-core-templates-for-single-page-apps-spas)

[Source code changes](https://github.com/mono/monodevelop/commit/b533bd7ba8d88c4ff82415d911ebd2d27c224f37)